# Can we move data objects up and down in pimcore 5, by default it is ascending?

Tags: pimcore-v5

I am trying to move some objects up to any object in the same folder but it always remains in ascending order. Can we make it as custom by which we can move any object to any place, if yes then how? I am using pimcore 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the objects according to the index by right-clicking on a folder or object -> Sort Children by -> Index.

This feature was released with 5.2.2. If you can't update pimcore, you need to create an index in your object.

[Sort by index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bja20.png)

Comment: Thanks..but i am not able to see that Sort Children by option in pimcore 5.2.Is there any other way?

Comment: If you can't update pimcore, you need to create an index in your object.